# Does double majoring with math in undergrad help one grasp TCS topics more easier?

Tags: soft-question

I'm a CS major. However, a lot of TCS topics seem to be in the realm of pure math. Should I add a math major to complement understanding and for a future career in TCS?

Comment: yep ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: It's not, strictly speaking, necessary. I've seen plenty of good TCS people come from "only" a CS background with math they picked up along the way. But yes, if it's an option available to you that you would enjoy and not be a burden, then I would recommend adding a math major (for the purposes of TCS) 100% :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three benefits of math classes:

- Knowledge of particular mathematical topics that are useful in TCS. This is a bit specific to the circumstance, but of course it helps! Probability, combinatorics, algebra, sometimes analysis, number theory, logic, ....
- Mathematical maturity, general comfort with proofs and mathematical reasoning. Very important.
- Showing your qualifications on grad school applications.

But I think the specific classes you take and skills you gain are more important than whether you officially major in math or not.

Comment: 'algebra' but "sometimes" 'analysis, number theory'?

Comment: @mathworker21 what is your question or comment? I think which classes are more useful varies throughout TCS.